# Why do my images get positioned below each other when I set all of them to col-6?

Tags: php, html, css, foreach, bootstrap-4

I don't know why my images get positioned below each other even though they are inside a col-6 Bootstrap div. I want them to be next to each other, not below.
Code, in case it's unreadable in the text below: https://i.stack.imgur.com/k60Ed.jpg

Page: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qq4m.jpg

I have already tried putting the col-6 inside the foreach block, but it only made the second image smaller. I don't know what else to try.

```
<section id="listaoldal">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
           <div class="col-6">
           <?php foreach ($characterDetails as $key):?>
           <img data-toggle="modal" data-target="#<?= $key['modal']?>"                              class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block my-5 ddimages"src="characters/<?=$key['link'] ?>">
           <?php endforeach;?>
```

Well, I expect the images to be next to each other like they should be not below.

Comment: Nah, that didn't do anything. I just forgot to add it to the things I've already tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

foreach out of col-6.

`<?php foreach ($characterDetails as $key):?>
     <div class="col-6"><img ... /></div>
    <?=endforeach?>`

Comment: We've got a winner. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<section id="listaoldal">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
 <?php foreach ($characterDetails as $key):?>
           <div class="col-6">
           <img data-toggle="modal" data-target="#<?= $key['modal']?>"                              class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block my-5 ddimages"src="characters/<?=$key['link'] ?>">
           <?php endforeach;?>
```

Comment: I don't think you've read this part of the question: 
"I have already tried putting the col-6 inside the foreach block, but it only made the second image smaller. I don't know what else to try."

Answer (score 0):

Actually your images are placed into one "col-6" you have to create one for each images, like this:

```
<div class="col-6">
    <img .../>
</div>
<div class="col-6">
    <img .../>
</div>
<div class="col-6">
    <img .../>
</div>
...
```

Quick exemple of what you could use to make it work :

```
<section id="listaoldal">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <?php foreach ($characterDetails as $key):?>
          <div class="col-6">
              <img data-toggle="modal" data-target="#<?= $key['modal']?>"                              class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block my-5 ddimages"src="characters/<?=$key['link'] ?>">
          </div>
        <?php endforeach;?>
```

I recommend you to read more about Bootstrap's Grid system:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/